# extract integer from td

Tags: javascript, jquery

if I have a simple html table:

```
<table>
  <tr>
    <th>header</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td class="count test">423</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

how do I extract the integer from the td so that I can act on it?
the following code returns undefined:

```
function changeCount(){
    var count = $("td.count.test").val();
    alert(count);   
}
changeCount();
```

complete html:

```
<html>
 <head>
     <title>Creation of array object in javascript</title>
     <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js" ></script>
     <script language="javascript" >


    function changeCount(){
        var count = $("td.count.test").text();
        console.log(count); 
    }
    changeCount();
    </script>

    <style>
    td{width:200px;text-align:center;}
    </style>
</head>
<body>
<table>
    <tr>
        <th>header</th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td class="count test">423</td>
    </tr>
</table>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: use text() instead of val()

Comment: text() returns an empty string

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not `.val()` for a `<td>`, but `.text()`.

```
function changeCount(){
    var count = $("td.count.test").text();
    alert(count);   
}
```

Note that if there are multiple such `<td>` elements, that'll return the contents of the first one in the DOM.

The `.val()` method is for getting the "value" attribute of `<input>`, `<select>`, and `<textarea>` elements. In either case, the DOM access will give you a string. If you need to do computation with the value, then it should be coerced to be a number via `parseInt()` or one of several other tricks.

Comment: And if you want to use it for math operations, parseInt(count, 10).

Comment: @kjarsenal not if your HTML really looks like that it doesn't. Where exactly in your code are you calling the function?

Comment: added complete html for clarity

Comment: @kjarsenal you're trying to examine the `<td>` before the browser has even seen the `<body>`.  Put your `<script>` tag at the very end of the body and try again.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is you are trying to access stuff through JavaScript which is not available in the DOM tree at the time your function is executed. You need to make sure `changeCount()`  is fired after the whole DOM tree has been loaded or at least after the element that is required by your function is part of the document DOM tree.

```
<html>
 <head>
     <title>Creation of array object in javascript</title>
     <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js" ></script>
     <script language="javascript" >


    function changeCount(){
        var count = $("td.count.test").text();
        console.log(count); 
    }
    $(document).ready(function(){
        changeCount();
    });        
    </script>

    <style>
    td{width:200px;text-align:center;}
    </style>
</head>
<body>
<table>
    <tr>
        <th>header</th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td class="count test">four twenty three</td>
    </tr>
</table>
</body>
</html>
```